# LDAP sorting with ldap_get_next_page_s results in error LDAP_UNAVAILABLE_CRIT_EXTENSION

Tags: c++, sorting, ldap

Im trying to sort the results obtained with Ldap query. Without sorting everythng works file but when i try to use sorting i get  LDAP_UNAVAILABLE_CRIT_EXTENSION error.
Here is the sample code

```
ULONG ulVersion = LDAP_VERSION3;
ret = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_VERSION, & ulVersion)

LDAPSerach * pSearch;

LDAPSortControl SortControl

SortControl.sk_attrttype = "SamAccountName"
SortControl.sk_matchruleoid = NULL;
SortControl.sk_reverseorder = 0;

PLDAPSortControl pSortControl[2];

pSortControl[0] = & SortControl;
pSortControl[1] = NULL

pSearch = ldap_search_init_page( ld, ... NULL for attribs, ...
,pSortControl)

ret = ldap_get_next_page(ld,pSearch, .. , &result);
```

Please let me know where im going wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're not going wrong. The server doesn't support the feature.

Comment: When you say server doesnot support it. Which server do u mean?? Ldap server?? i am using ldap version 3 that supports sorting

Comment: Yes, the LDAP server does not support the server side sorting control.

Comment: When I say 'the server doesn't support the feature' I mean the LDAP server you're using, whatever that is. 'Version 3' only refers to the protocol version, which everybody uses.